# What is this Austrian dish? It resembles potato croquettes?

Tags: food-identification

I'm searching for a recipe or just anyone who knows this dish, I think it sounds like 'rostitachen' but I can't find any recipes online or anything about it!

They are like potato croquettes filled with cheese and veg or mushrooms.

Answer (score 8):

The term you are looking for is **"Rösti-Taschen"**. Alternatives could be for example "Rösti Tasch**erl**" (Austrian diminuitive) or "(gefüllte) **Kartoffel**taschen" (denoting the ingredient).

They are sold as convenience food by various suppliers ([1](https://www.11er.at/unsere-produkte/feine-11er-roesti-taschen/), [2](https://produkte.migros.ch/delicious-roestitasche-kaese)), recipes to make them from scratch seem rather scarce (and typically in German).

The base principle is making a dough from starchy potatoes, egg, flour butter etc., wrap it round the desired filling and deep (or shallow) -fry them in fat. Breading them is optional, but can help them keep their shape. I suggest starting with a recipe for croquettes and a recipe for the desired type of filling, then combine them. Tweak as necessary.